# How should I strip invalid XML characters from a stream in J2ME? org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Invalid character

Tags: xml, blackberry, java-me, sax, rim-4.2

This code is running on Blackberry JDE v4.2.1  It's in a method that makes web API calls that return XML.  Sometimes, the XML returned is not well formed and I need to strip out any invalid characters prior to parse.

Currently, I get: `org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Invalid character '' encountered`.

I would like to see ideas of a fast way to attach an invalid character stripper on the input stream so that the stream just flows through the validator/stripper and into the parse call.  i.e. I'm trying to avoid saving the content of the stream.

Existing code:

**handler** is an override of `DefaultHandler`
**url** is a String containing the API `URL`

```
hconn = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url,Connector.READ_WRITE,true);

...

try{
   XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
   InputStream input = hconn.openInputStream();
   parser.parse(input, handler);
   input.close();
} catch (SAXException e) {
   Logger.getInstance().error("getViaHTTP() - SAXException - "+e.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's difficult to attach a stripper on the InputStream because streams are byte-oriented.  It might make more sense to do it on a [Reader](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html).  You could make something like a StripReader that wraps a another reader and deals with errors.  Below is a quick, untested, proof of concept for this:

```
public class StripReader extends Reader
{
    private Reader in;
    public StripReader(Reader in)
    {
    this.in = in;
    }

    public boolean markSupported()
    {
    return false;
    }

    public void mark(int readLimit)
    {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Mark not supported");
    }

    public void reset()
    {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Reset not supported");
    }

    public int read() throws IOException
    {
    int next;
    do
    {
        next = in.read();
    } while(!(next == -1 || Character.isValidCodePoint(next)));

    return next; 
    }

    public void close() throws IOException
    {
    in.close();
    }

    public int read(char[] cbuf, int off, int len) throws IOException
    {
    int i, next = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        next = read();
        if(next == -1)
        break;
        cbuf[off + i] = (char)next;
    }
    if(i == 0 && next == -1)
        return -1;
    else
        return i;
    }

    public int read(char[] cbuf) throws IOException
    {
    return read(cbuf, 0, cbuf.length);
    }
}
```

You would then construct an [InputSource](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/xml/sax/InputSource.html) from then Reader then do the parse using the InputSource.

Comment: Since Blackberry apparently doesn't have FilterReader either, I modified the above not to use it.

Comment: RIM also doesn't include Character.isValidCodePoint()
I had to roll my own.  But, this method does seem to work - on the simulator at least.  Hopefully, it will also hold up and not be too slow on a real device.  Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.  Just be sure to test well.  It's unavoidably going to slow things down since every character must be (re-)checked.  However, I don't think I'm doing any unnecessary copying.  P.S. I'm curious as to how you implemented isValidCodePoint.

Comment: It's not going to show up well in this comments block but here is the method I use for validating an XML character:

    private boolean isValidXMLChar(int ch)
    {
        if ((ch == 0x9) ||
            (ch == 0xA) ||
            (ch == 0xD) ||
            ((ch >= 0x20) && (ch <= 0xD7FF)) ||
            ((ch >= 0xE000) && (ch <= 0xFFFD)) ||
            ((ch >= 0x10000) && (ch <= 0x10FFFF)))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

Answer (score 0):

Use a [FilterInputStream](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/FilterInputStream.html).  Override [FilterInputStream#read](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/FilterInputStream.html#read()) to filter the offending bytes.

Comment: Problem is that requires duplicating the character-decoding logic in the stream.

Comment: There may not be a way to avoid that without customizing XMLParser?

Comment: RIM doesn't have FilterInputStream http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.2.1api/index.html

Comment: Why not just use a customized XMLParser only when there is a SAXException?  It would seem that if you get a bad xml file then it would be best to reject the entire file as the damaged part may lead to bad data being extracted.